# How to display value contained in Result or a generic message if Result is Err

Tags: rust

I would like to print `T` if `Ok(T)` or a generic message and do this as part of the same `println!()` statement.

My Current solution which works is:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: std::io::Result<i32> = Ok(54);
    println!("hello {} ", x.map(|i| i.to_string()).unwrap_or("Bad".to_string()));
}
```

Is there a simpler and more efficient way that would leverage the `Display` trait instead of needing to convert to string inside `map` and `unwrap_or`?

Comment: Nit: don't use `unwrap_or` in this case, as it will always construct the string. Use `unwrap_or_else` with a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast each of the `Result` values as `&dyn Display`

```rust
let display = match &x {
    Ok(i) => i as &dyn Display,
    Err(_) => &"error" as &dyn Display,
};

// or with map

let display = x
    .as_ref()
    .map(|x| x as &dyn Display)
    .unwrap_or_else(|_| &"error" as &dyn Display);

println!(
    "hello {} ",
     display
)
```

Both can be in-lined into the `println!`, I have just separated them for readability.

Comment: Fyi: You can replace one of the `as &dyn Display` with `as _`. If you so please.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted solution works and answers your question exactly, I don't think it's the most readable <s>(or performant)</s>. (Correction: it's in fact faster.) A trait object feels like overkill to me. Consider using the same approach as yours, but instead, merge the `map()` and `unwrap_or()` into `map_or()` (or `map_or_else()`, to avoid an unnecessary heap allocation).

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let x: io::Result<i32> = Ok(54);
    println!("Hello, {}.", x.map_or_else(|_err| "Bad".into(), |i| i.to_string()));
}
```

[Run this snippet on Rust Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f4a0a16fa0c3c1c56ac2d46ce6bf3442)

If you're not going to use the error value, you can make the code a touch more concise by renaming `_err` to `_`.

---

On the other hand, if you're going to be doing this often and in many places, you can create a wrapper type and implement your `Display` logic for that.

```
use std::fmt::{self, Display};
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let x: io::Result<i32> = Ok(54);
    println!("Hello, {}.", PrintableResult(&x));
}

struct PrintableResult<'a, T: Display, E>(&'a Result<T, E>);

impl<'a, T: Display, E> Display for PrintableResult<'a, T, E> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}",
            self.0
                .as_ref()
                .map_or_else(|_| "Bad".into(), |val| val.to_string())
        )
    }
}
```

[Run this snippet on Rust Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2730e479f8c26709244c2586b11cf7db)

If you don't mind `PrintableResult` taking ownership of your `Result` value, you can drop the borrow and the lifetime specifier with it.

If you'd like, you can also implement a `to_printable()` extension method for `Result` (via a trait).

```
// ...

fn main() {
    let x: io::Result<i32> = Ok(54);
    println!("Hello, {}.", x.to_printable());
    
    let y: Result<i32, &'static str> = Err("Something went wrong.");
    println!("Hello, {}.", y.to_printable());
}

// ...

trait ToPrintable<T: Display, E> {
    fn to_printable(&self) -> PrintableResult<T, E>;
}

impl<T: Display, E> ToPrintable<T, E> for Result<T, E> {
    fn to_printable(&self) -> PrintableResult<T, E> {
        PrintableResult(&self)
    }
}
```

[Run this snippet on Rust Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b65738d700b555ed8373f320d1ffce8)

Comment: I agree it is not the most readable, but 1) it is definitely faster than your `map_or_else()`, and I think it is the same speed as your wrapper, and 2) I consider using `map_or[_else]()` unreadable too, because of its swapped argument order.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I thought the layer of indirection from a trait object would add overhead, but in hindsight, allocating a new `String` is worse. I tested it, and you're right. It's a good 50-70% faster. As for the `map_or_else`'s order, I've heard your complaint before, so you're definitely not alone in that, but I personally think it makes sense: `map or "bad", [do the mapping]`. It reads naturally. (BTW, the wrapper is the same speed as my `map_or_else`, since it does the same exact thing.)